# A function to extract filtered variables from sequential dataframes (R)

Tags: r

**Problem**:

Many government datasets (which I work with) are produced yearly (cross-section data), in sequentially labelled `.csv` files and with, roughly, the same set of variables across years. These datasets are large, with hundreds of columns and thousands or millions cases. However, often I have to produce time-trend analysis of indicators produced from just a few variables for a subset of cases.

For example, the annual national household survey has information downloadable in files called "`pnad_XXXX.csv`", where "XXXX" is replaced by the year of reference. The same pattern applies to other government datasets, such as the school census, the labor market census , etc.

In the "pnad", I need to produce some trend analysis of educational indicators across time, from files named "`pnad_2004.csv`" to "`pnad_2020.csv`". Let´s assume that educational variables are  "var_3032", "var_3033", "var_3034", "var_3035" "var_3036", "var_3037" and I also need some information from individuals, contained in variables "var_0321", "var_0452" and "var_8878". I need only individuals aged between 5 and 19 (`var_0321 > 4 & var_0321 < 20`)

**What I did:**

Until now, what I did is to open each of the 17 files separately, select the variables I want, filter the data and save it in an object. After that I row-bind all 17 objects. For example:

```
library(dplyr)

pnad_2004 <- read.csv("pnad_2004.csv") %>% select(var_0321, var_0452, var_8878, var_3032, var_3033, var_3034, var_3035, var_3036, var_3037) %>% filter (var_0321 > 4 & var_0321 < 20)

pnad_2005 <- read.csv("pnad_2005.csv") %>% select(var_0321, var_0452, var_8878, var_3032, var_3033, var_3034, var_3035, var_3036, var_3037) %>% filter (var_0321 > 4 & var_0321 < 20)

.
. (do the same for each one of the 17 files)
.

pnad_2020 <- read.csv("pnad_2020.csv") %>% select(var_0321, var_0452, var_8878, var_3032, var_3033, var_3034, var_3035, var_3036, var_3037) %>% filter (var_0321 > 4 & var_0321 < 20)

pnad_2004_2020 <- bind_rows(pnad_2004, pnad_2005, pnad_2006, ..., pnad_2020)
```

Assuming that all files are saved in the project folder/working directory.

**What I want**:

I would like to write a generalizable function, that would do the same as of the above code, but with only a few inputs. Ideally, this function would also be generalizable to work with other government datasets that have the same sequential "name_year" pattern.

I am still learning how to write functions in R, but I hope the following serves as an ilustrative example of what I am trying to do:

```
#As the list of variables are specific for each set of dataframes, I would first need to save the names of the variables I want in a vector. 

pnad_vars <- c("var_0321", "var_0452", "var_8878", "var_3032", "var_3033", "var_3034", "var_3035", "var_3036", "var_3037")

#Then the function would look something like:

stack_data <- function(name, first_year, last_year, var_list, condition) {
  for i in start_date:end_date {
    name_i <- read.csv("name_i.csv") %>% select(var_list) %>% filter(condition) 
  }
  bind_rows(first_year:last_year)
}

#The working function would be something like:

pnad_2004_2020 <- stack_data("pnad", "2004", "2020", pnad_vars, "var_0321 > 4 & var_0321 < 20")
```

Answer (score 0):

If the csv files are in the working directory inside R. We can try this code.

```
library(stringr)
library(tidyverse)


pnad_vars <- c("var_0321", "var_0452", "var_8878", "var_3032", "var_3033", "var_3034", "var_3035", "var_3036", "var_3037")

#these names are located in a directory that can be set with setwd()
csv_names <- str_c('pnad_', as.character(seq(2004, 2020, 1)), '.csv')

global_names <- str_c('pnad_', as.character(seq(2004, 2020, 1)))

#for every name (eg: pnad_2015.csv) a global variable named the pnad_theYear
map2(csv_names, global_names,  ~{
    assign(..2, read.csv(..1) %>% select(pnad_vars) %>% filter(condition))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It will work best if you work from lists. To generate your vector of filenames within your function example, you'll want to do something like: `paste0(name,rep(first_year:last_year),".csv")` Here is a more filled out function for populating a list:

```
Your_list<-list() #empty to start
stack_data <- function(name, first_year, last_year, var_list, condition) {
  #create the list of files you want
  files<-paste0(name,rep(first_year:last_year),".csv")
  #assign each read to index of a list
  for i in 1:length(files) {
    Your_list[[i]] <- read.csv(files[i]) %>% select(var_list) %>% filter(condition) 
  }
}
```

You can combine list elements in a df with something like this:

```
as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(Your_list),nrow=length(Your_list),byrow=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
pnad_2004_2020 <-  file_list%>%
   map(~read.csv(.x) %>%
       select(var_0321, var_0452, var_8878, var_3032, var_3033, 
              var_3034, var_3035, var_3036, var_3037) %>%
       filter(var_0321 > 4 & var_0321 < 20), .id = 'file')
```

`file_list` is the list of csv files to be read in

In Base R you could do:

```
do.call(rbind, 
   lapply(file_list, function(x) 
           subset(read.csv(x), 
                 var_0321 > 4 & var_0321 < 20
                 select = c(var_0321, var_0452, var_8878, var_3032, var_3033, 
                     var_3034, var_3035, var_3036, var_3037))))
```